# Indexer working with both normal and jagged arrays

Tags: c#

I have two classes:

```
//The class with the Main method
    Six ujhb = new(4);
//fill in all the arrays but not the inner arrays
    for(int i = 0; i < ujhb.Size; i++) {
        ujhb[i] = new int[i+1];
        Console.WriteLine(ujhb[i]);
    }
//get a value of a specific inner array
    Console.WriteLine(ujhb[2][0]);

class Six {

    int[][] a;
    public int Size;

    public Six(int v) {
        a = new int[v][];
        Size = v;
    }

    public int[] this[int index] {
        get {
            return a[index];
        }

        set {
            a[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So I have an Indexer which gets an array or sets an array.
I just don'tunderstand how does this line work:

```
Console.WriteLine(ujhb[2][0]);
```

Considering that the indexer is told to return int[ ] s  not int[ ][ ] s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's two operations.

1.) `ujhb[2]` first calls the indexer with `index == 2`, which returns an array (`int[]`).

2.) Then `[0]` accesses the item at index `0` in that array.

Basically, it's short for:

```
var array = ujhb[2]; // indexer call
var item = array[0]; // array access
Console.WriteLine(item);
```